# Will there be potential issues running another SignalR hub within Blazor Server?

Tags: .net, blazor, signalr, blazor-server-side

I have a scenario where I will be hosting a **separate SignalR Hub within a Blazor Server** application (which obviously will already have its own **Blazor Hub**'. This SignalR Hub will be busy / high usage with lots of clients.

- Was wondering if there will be any issues or limitations that I might
  be aware of?
- Will the SignalR connections get confused? Connected to wrong port?
- Any port exhaustion issues?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There won't be any problems. Depending on your scenario you might want to run it on a separate server simply because of performance, especially if you have high traffic.